# why cant i get value of $accept_request_id

Tags: php, html

```
<form method="post>
    <button input type="submit" id="click" class="btn btn-info " name="<?php echo$accept_request_id; ?>"></button> 
</form>
```

Why can't I get value of **$accept_request_id**? I use following code

```
if(isset($_POST[$accept_request_id])) {
     $accept_request_id=$_POST['accept_request_id'];
}
```

Comment: Did you ever set `$accept_request_id` before trying to use it?  Why are you over-writing it like that?  What is the actual error you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code to get value of form. This will work

```
<form method="post>
    <input type="hidden" name="accept_request_id" value="<?php echo $accept_request_id ?>" />
    <button input type="submit" id="click" class="btn btn-info">Submit
    </button>
</form>

if(isset($_POST['accept_request_id'])) {
     $accept_request_id = $_POST['accept_request_id'];
}
```